# Importing StaggeredGridView library - Parcel.CreateIntArry() not applicable for Parcel.CreateIntArry(int[]) error

Tags: java, android, android-library

I've been trying to import [StaggeredGridView](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView) library in to eclipse. Everything works fine except an error in the [StaggeredGridView.java](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView/blob/master/src/com/origamilabs/library/views/StaggeredGridView.java).

In the following method of the class

```
    private SavedState(Parcel in) {
        super(in);
        firstId = in.readLong();
        position = in.readInt();
        in.createIntArray(topOffsets); //error here
        in.readTypedList(mapping, ColMap.CREATOR);

    }
```

eclipse shows the error

> The method createIntArray() in the type Parcel is not applicable for
>   the arguments (int[])

Any suggestions how to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is showing because the [`Parcel`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html) class does not define a `createIntArray(int[])` method that takes a parameter. There are two options:

1. `createIntArray()` (without parameter)
2. `readIntArray(int[])`

Based on the [commit that's now causing the compile error](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView/commit/98ad9433ab572faa18d2a87a688bf3a932bde608), it used to be `readIntArray(int[])`. I'm not sure why it was changed in the first place, but it seems to be related to the StaggeredGridView not always being restored properly. For the time being, you may just want to change it back to how it was before, and keep an eye out for any new commits to the git repo.